# static data for mutual funds/hedge funds

Tags: mutual-funds, hedge-funds

What is the meaning of the phrase 'static data' as applied to a hedge fund or a mutual fund? Or is it purely a programmer's lingo with little business meaning? The words taken individually do hint it is programmers lingo:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really my field, but I believe it's all the information that doesn't change (i.e. isn't "real-time") about the business of hedge funds.  For example, [this site](http://www.milestonegroup.com.au/products/pcontrol_unitised_order_management.html) quotes:

> The product maintains comprehensive static data records including assets, 
>      depositories, accounts, settlement instructions and a wide range of 
>      supporting data...

Comment: @Pacerier: that's why I quoted the relevant part. :-)